# Unique Constraint Violation in EclipseLink under GlassFish 4.1 with MySql

Tags: mysql, jpa, glassfish, eclipselink

I've been stumped by this issue in my application for a few days.

I have two tables `event` and `guest` related by a `ManyToMany` relationship, mapped by table `event_guest`. Since I need to access the join table to store extra attributes there, I also have an entity for that table and have two `ManyToOne` with the corresponding `OneToMany` relationships in the main entities.

Here's the relevant code:

event entity

```
@Entity
@Table ( name = "event" )
public class EventEntity implements Serializable {

@Id
@Column ( name = "event_id", insertable = false)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

...

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "event")
private List<EventGuestEntity> eventGuest;

...

}
```

guest entity

```
@Entity
@Table ( name = "guest" )
public class GuestEntity implements Serializable {

@Id
@Column(name = "guest_id")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Integer id;

...

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "guest")
private List<EventGuestEntity> eventGuest;

...

}
```

join table entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "event_guest")
public class EventGuestEntity implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "event_guest_id")
private Long id;

...

@ManyToOne
@NotNull
@JoinColumn(name = "event_id")
private EventEntity event;

@ManyToOne
@NotNull
@JoinColumn(name = "guest_id")
private GuestEntity guest;

...

}
```

And here the EJB code that actually associates guests to events:

```
@Stateless
public class GuestBean implements GuestBeanLocal {
    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(GuestBean.class.getName());

    private GuestEntity guestEntity;
    private EventEntity eventEntity;
    private EventGuestEntity eventGuestEntity;

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    public Boolean associateGuestToEvent(Long eventId, int guestId) {
        guestEntity = em.find(GuestEntity.class, guestId);
        eventEntity = em.find(EventEntity.class, eventId);

        try {
            Query q = em.createNamedQuery("getEventGuestByIds").setParameter("event", eventId).setParameter("guest", guestId);
            eventGuestEntity = (EventGuestEntity) q.getSingleResult();
        } catch (NoResultException e) {
            eventGuestEntity = null;
        }

        if (eventGuestEntity == null) {
            eventGuestEntity = new EventGuestEntity();
            eventGuestEntity.setGuest(guestEntity);

            eventGuestEntity.setEvent(eventEntity);
            List<EventGuestEntity> listFromGuest = guestEntity.getEventGuest();
            listFromGuest.add(eventGuestEntity);

            List<EventGuestEntity> listFromEvent = eventEntity.getEventGuest();
            listFromEvent.add(eventGuestEntity);

            try {
                em.merge(eventGuestEntity);
                em.merge(eventEntity);
                em.merge(guestEntity);
                em.flush();
                em.refresh(eventEntity);
                em.refresh(guestEntity);
                return true;
            } catch (PersistenceException e) {
                logger.debug("Error while adding guest entity to event entity list.");
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            return true;
        }
```

So far so good, everything seems to work fine. Guests can be associated to events and later disassociated from events, then re-associated and everything works.

Until I stress the application with even the smallest amount of load. If I use JMeter to test it with 2 threads it's enough to make things start to fail.

And this is where it gets weird. The actual functionality that associates guests to events works like a charm. But whatever comes next in my JMeter test, fails with a unique constraint violation as such:

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '40-3' for key 'uq_event_id_guest_id_idx'
Error Code: 1062
Call: INSERT INTO event_guest (event_id, guest_id) VALUES (?, ?)
        bind => [40, 3]
```

This makes a functionality that has nothing to do with associating guests to events (and doesn't even touch the guest entity or the join table entity) fail. I've even changed the order of the tests to see if it would break any functionality and it appears that any of them presents the same behavior. One thing I've noticed that makes the problem disappear is if I add a constant delay between the requests in JMeter. 100ms is enough to make it work normally.

I've enabled eclipselink logging and set it to the ALL level. I've looked through the generated log but didn't find anything incriminating. Right now, my only idea is to test other JPA providers and/or other Application Servers to isolate whether it's my application or one of those two components. But I'd bet it's my code, so I'm here asking for help.

Comment: Why do you suspect JPA is the issue?  Have you verified your application won't try to pass 40 and 3 as the event/guest id values in multiple times under load, and that the first thread might not have completed inserting the new EventGuestEntity before the second thread also determines it needs to create a new EventGuestEntity?

Comment: That's the point. The functionality that fails doesn't have anything to do with the EventGuestEntity. I've tried executing various functionalities after the guest association and all of them fail with the same error. As far as the first thread not having completed inserting, I was under the assumption that the EJB container would take care of controlling the transactions so that this wouldn't happen. As far as I can tell, my issue isn't that one thread is interfering with the other. It's the subsequent request made by the same thread that fails.

Comment: You have shown the EventGuestEntity's event and guest relationship, but not EventGuestEntity's id fields or how they are set even though you are presumably querying on them with your named query.  Does em.find work instead of your named query?  Why are you using merge instead of persist on the created eventGuestEntity?  Does the getEventGuest lists you've obtain already contain a EventGuestEntity similar to the one you are trying to add?  If this is multithreaded, I would recommend optimistic locking, as transactions do not prevent data overwrites or issues like this.

Comment: @Chris I've added the id fields to the OP. But the named query does not query on the EventGuestEntity's id field. It queries on both the EventEntity's id and GuestEntity's id. So no, I can't use em.find because those are not my table's id. About merge, quite frankly I don't remember. I've tried dozens of variations before posting and this is the one that got closer to working like it should. I'll try it again with persist and post the results later. About the lists, it shouldn't contain this object since I've checked whether it exists before.

Comment: Continuing: This is multithreaded since it runs on Glassfish, but I was able to replicate the issue even with just one thread, just so long as the requests happen very close to each other, with no delays in between.

Comment: Turn on EclipseLink logging to all or finest to see the statements as they are executed, and try to log the transactions.  This seems like a timing issue, such that your query executes before the thread inserting has completed its commit in the database.

Comment: @Chris that's the last thing I tried but at that time, I was only able to replicate the issue with more than one thread. That way it was hard to map each transaction to the functionality being tested. I'll try to replicate the problem with one thread again and enable logging then to try to see what's going on. But I still don't understand why an EJB that has nothing to do with that entity is trying to insert it.